# Access IOwinRequest in Self Hosted IdentityServer3 CustomGrant Validator

Tags: dependency-injection, owin, identityserver3

I am using a self hosted (i.e. console app) IdentityServer3 application.  I have implemented a CustomGrant validator.

How to I get access to the IOwinRequest and IOwinResponse contexts from this CustomGrantValidator?

Can it be done using Dependency Injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the `OwinEnvironmentService` into your validator.

From there you can create the OwinContext like

`var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironmentService.Environment);`

The context in turn has the request and response objects.

Comment: Thank you for the help and all the work you do on IdentityServer!

Answer (score 1):

The services from IdentityServer's DI are available via the `ResolveDependency` OWIN extension: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/owin.html. To use these OWIN extensions your code must be running in the pipeline after IdentityServer.

Comment: Thank you for the help and all the work you do on IdentityServer!